# Android In-App updates api cannot work on the Android TV device

Tags: android, android-tv, in-app-update

From the doc of https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates,
we tested the in-app updates api with below code on a Android TV device(Android 8.0) and the version of the play store is 16.7.31

```
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
          && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
    }
});
```

However, the test api result always fail and showed as below,
com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -3

we checked the error code definition from the site: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode.html#error_install_not_allowed
, and found that which means "The API is not available on this device."

Why the in-app updates api cannot work on this device? Is this API not available on Android TV?

Answer (score 2):

Your device does not support in-app update because it’s Android TV.
[In-App Update support page](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) says that only mobiles, tablets and Chrome OS devices are supported.

For Android TV - no luck. I have the same issue with my Android TV app.